# Angular 9- add line numbers while displaying a dynamic json response

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, less

I have to display a dynamic Json response coming from the server which looks something like this

```
{
  responseBody: {
    menu: {
      id: 'file',
        value: 'File',
      },
    },
  }
  status: 200,
}
```

I am parsing the responseBody string to pretty print it. But, I have to display the responseBody (which can be JSON, XML or string) with line numbers like this
[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kbFr.png)

How can display this response along with the line number?

Comment: do not post pictures with code, attach the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the module ngx-highlightjs to do this.

[ngx-highlightjs NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-highlightjs)

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-highlightjs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)